# transition-style: preserve-3d and positioning in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions

I'm getting a strange behaviour in Firefox. It's only applying my css 3D transform to absolute positioned elements within a link, but applying the transforms to all elements if not enclosed in an a tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/jhpdf/aUS3P/

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <div class="l35">
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/luckypdftv" target="_blank">
                <img class="drop" src="http://luckypdf.com/new/youtubew-t blur.png" />
                <img class="front" src="http://luckypdf.com/new/youtubew-t.png" />
            </a>
       </div>       
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="l35">
            <img class="drop" src="http://luckypdf.com/new/dailymail blur.png" />
            <img class="front" src="http://luckypdf.com/new/dailymail.png" />   
        </div>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
    .list {
    perspective:1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective:1000px;
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    margin: 50px auto;

}

.list li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: 1;
user-drag: none;
    -moz-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -o-user-drag: none;
    -ms-user-drag: none;
user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}


.list li div {
    margin: 5px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


.list a {
    height:300px;
}




.list li img {
display:block; 
margin:auto; 
max-width: 200px; 
max-height:100px; 

        transition:  2s;
    -webkit-transition:  2s;
    -moz-transition:  2s;
    -o-transition:  2s;
    -ms-transition:  2s;
}
.list img.front {   
    z-index: 0;
    transform: translateZ(-100px);
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(-100px);
        -o-transform: translateZ(-100px);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(-100px);
}

.list li:hover img.front {
    transform: translateZ(100px); 
        -moz-transform: translateZ(100px); 
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
    z-index: 3;
}

.list img.drop {

    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transform: translateZ(-120px);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-120px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-120px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(-120px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(-120px);
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;

}

.list li:hover img.drop {
    transform: translateZ(50px); 
        -moz-transform: translateZ(50px); 
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);

}
```

Fine in safari, would be great to know why this is happening. Sorry the code's a bit of a mess.